# JSON filtering for multiple keys runs slow

Tags: javascript, json, performance, filtering

My code works, but it seems to be running exceptionally slow.

I have an array of values to search and I have a `JSON` that I'm filtering.

```
var JSONPull;
var FilterJSON = [];
var TypeIDs = [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,11399,1230,17470,17471,1228,17463,17464,1224,17459,17460,18,17455,17456,1227,17867,17868,20,17452,17453,1226,17448,17449,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1229,17865,17866,1232,17436,17437,19,17466,17467,1225,17432,17433,1223,17428,17429,22,17425,17426,11396,17869,17870];

fetch('URL API')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        JSONPull = out;
        TypeIDs.forEach(function (index){
            FilterJSON = JSONPull.filter((element) => {
                console.log("index: "+index);
                console.log(element);
                console.log("type_id: "+ element.type_id);
                element.type_id === index;
            });
        })
    })
```

The `console.logs` are more just to watch the code while testing, but definitely shouldn't be causing these performance issues.

Could you please advise me on performance optimisation?

Comment: I think this question should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, didn't know that was a thing... thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing this now, there's a full loop over every single data item for the number of IDs you're looking for.  I'd assume you have far more records than you do IDs that you're looking for, so you should refactor this a bit, and remove a whole callback/closure in the process.  Lean on some browser optimized code.

```
out.filter(element => TypeIDs.includes(element.type_id))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Also, just as a point of review... your casing of variables is non-standard and makes it difficult to skim through your code.  (Not that the compiler cares...)

And, `console.log()` can *definitely* cause performance issues.

Comment: It should be also mentioned though that `includes` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility) in IE.

Comment: @Zuckerberg Sure, mention it all you want.  It's a non-issue for almost everyone at this point.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes  And while you're at it, also mention that if you're still targeting a 7 year old browser, you'd be using a bundler, a transpiler (for that ES6 syntax), and a bunch of polyfills that will take care of this for you anyway.

Comment: @Zuckerberg Did you know that the Fetch API doesn't work in IE 11 either?  The question makes good use of the Fetch API.

Comment: This is a more personal project, and I don't use IE/Edge unless it's to download another browser on a new computer in my personal use... Thanks for the heads up. Regarding  the code, am I reading this right? That it should return where any objects in out where type_id is in TypeIDs array will be returned? I've tested the code, and the returned objects seem light in quantity

Comment: @Blackard All of this stuff works even in Edge, don't mind Zuckerberg's comments.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had another issue, where the API limited to 1000 objects per call, so I had to iterate through the type_id to add as a filter the API, my code is below, and works great. Thanks for all of the help everyone.

```
var mergedJSON = [];
var TypeIDs = [34,35,36,37,38,39,40,11399,1230,17470,17471,1228,17463,17464,1224,17459,17460,18,17455,17456,1227,17867,17868,20,17452,17453,1226,17448,17449,21,17440,17441,1231,17444,17445,1229,17865,17866,1232,17436,17437,19,17466,17467,1225,17432,17433,1223,17428,17429,22,17425,17426,11396,17869,17870];

TypeIDs.forEach(function(index){

fetch(`https://<URL here>&order_type=all&type_id=${index}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        out.forEach(function (element){
            mergedJSON.push(element);
        })
    })
})
```

and I apologize for the nonstandard casing, I've always been more of a solitary coder, so as long as my variables haven't been all caps I've sort of accepted it. I'll venture to be more standardized.